# Why can't Sass lists handle periods?

Tags: sass

In the Sass interactive console, I'm typing in `list-separator((div,p,h1))` and it is returning `comma` as expected. But when I type in `list-separator((div.hello,p,h1))`, it returns `SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...-separator((div": expected ")", was ".hello,p,h1))"`.

I know I could simply put quotes around div.hello to fix the problem, but **I'm trying to avoid putting quotes around the selectors because it takes away syntax highlighting.** And I don't understand why this list requires quotes in the first place.

I couldn't find anything in Google or in the docs about periods and how they mess with lists. Could some one explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser for strings does not allow periods (along with a multitude of other non-alphanumeric characters) unless it is within quotes.  The problem is not with lists:  you're just writing an invalid string.

Comment: Oh okay, I see now. Thanks!